# Waswasa During Prayers

Tags: salat, waswasa

I suffer from waswasa al qahri during Salah and just everyday life. In Salah, I get images of faces of people I see and I hate it. I don’t know what to do. So what I do is imagine the name of Allah in Arabic الله and sometimes in english that word Allah because it makes me focus and gives me comfort that I am praying to Allah. Is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

Brother 1 thing simple just reminde that you are standing in front of Allah(s.w.t) while praying think that Allah talah is watching you and praying namaz is talking with Allah (s.w.t) so think that you are talking with allah swt and allah swt is listening to you and you will start paying attention automaticly while praying